# I need to save data in mongodb and send this data to kafka all atomically

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka

I have spring boot application which persists data to mongodb and sends this data to kafka. I want this two processes to run atomically. That means if data is persisted to mongo then it should be sent to kafka. How can I do it?

Comment: Use Debezium to read data from Mongo into Kafka. Don't use a KafkaProducer in your app

Answer (score 1):

With Kafka itself you can't.

Kafka offers [transactions](https://www.confluent.io/de-de/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/), but they are restricted to write to multiple partitions in Kafka atomically. They are designed with stream processing in mind, so consuming from one topic and producing to another in one go - but a Kafka transaction cannot know whether a write command to mongo succeeded.

The usecase you have is something that appears regularly though. Usually you would use the [outbox pattern](https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/).  The answer is to only modify one of the two resources (the database or Apache Kafka) and drive the update of the second one based on that in an eventually consistent manner.

If you **really** need atomic writes, I believe it is possible to do so by relying on the ACID guarantees Mongo >= 4.2 gives you instead of Kafka's transactional guarantees. But this would mean you need to manage the Kafka offsets in Mongo.

If you have "Kafka the definitive guide, 2nd edition", there is a small chapter with more details about what exactly Kafka transactions can and cannot do and possible workarounds.

Comment: Is there a way to configure debezium to store in kafka not all the changes from mongo but a certain ones?

Comment: If you use the Debezium Connector in Kafka Connect, Single Message Transform (SMT) should have a filter option. In vanilla Debezium https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/transformations/filtering.html looks like it would be capable of this, but it seems like that is still "under active development". I never used Debezium myself though